# What is the format for the card? Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate an input where you insert the card number

I tried this format but the field is validated and if less than 16 numbers.

How can I change my constant so as not to accept less than 16 digits but no more

```
const card=  /^[0-9]*$/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `/^[0-9]{16}$/` for exact 16 digits, for less than use `{0,16}`

Comment: Does "not to accept less than 16 digits but no more" mean "exactly 16 digits"?

Answer (score 5):

`/^[0-9]{16}$/` --> Exactly 16 digits

`/^[0-9]{16,20}$/` --> Between 16 and 20 digits

`/^[0-9]{16,}$/` --> Minimum 16 Digits, no upper limit

`/^[0-9]{0,16}$/` --> Up to 16 digits

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 16 digit you could use:

```
const card = /^\d{16}$/;
```

or

```
const card = /^[0-9]{16}$/;
```

Less than 16 digit or 16 you could use:

```
const card = /^\d{0,16}$/;
```

or

```
const card = /^[0-9]{0,16}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curly brakets to define the number of valid occurances. Use `\d` for numbers - it is a synonmy to `[0-9]`:

```js
window.alert('123456789012345'.match(/^\d{0,15}$/)); // is OK
window.alert('1234567890123456'.match(/^\d{0,15}$/)); // is not OK
```

Try it out: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=93816